# facebook like button not displaying - after following facebook instructions absolutely

Tags: html, facebook, button, facebook-like

to offer the same sentiments as I've read on someone else's question about this "this is driving me crazy" I had thought that this was going to be a simple job, but I've spent ages scratching my head, wondering what's wrong. I've followed facebook instructions exactly, javascript is enabled, and I've put it on a web page that has absolutely nothing else on it (to be sure not to have accidentally hidden it through css).

I've read so many threads trying to work this out - if anyone out there can help me I really really would appreciate it...

www.tiardy.com/test.htm

```
<body>

<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://ww.tiardy.com" data-width="100" data-layout="standard" data-action="like" data-show-faces="true" data-share="true"></div>        

</body>
```

Comment: [Works...](http://jsfiddle.net/HCEDt/) And http://www.tiardy.com/test.htm
 works too.

Comment: great, thanks for checking that. It works for me too 'now'. I haven't changed a thing since I wrote this to the forum ???

Comment: great to catch that missing letter from the address at this stage though, thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Works for me, but I think

```
data-href="http://ww.tiardy.com"
```

should be

```
data-href="http://www.tiardy.com"
```